# Forcing forms authentication to redirect as a GET request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am using Forms authentication in IIS/MVC.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

I am issuing a HTTP PUT webapi request, and it times out because my cookie expired. The user quite rightly is redirected to http://Login but the request to the Login url is a PUT rather than a GET.

because my Controller only supports GET this results in a 404.

Is there a way to force the redirect to the login Url to always be a GET regardless of the type of the original request.

Answer (score 0):

When there is a redirect to Login action method, by default, the type is PUT even though the previous request is PUT/GET/POST/DELETE.Just tried your scenario. Had decorated an action with POST and it redirected to Login with type GET.Could you check if u missed anything else.

Comment: Do you mean the type is GET even though the previous request is one of the others? Otherwise your answer contradicts itself.